# No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.node in project with Vite

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite, loader, fsevents

I am making a project with Vite + React and it worked well until the end of last week, but all of a sudden, I got this error:

> No loader is configured for ".node" files:
>
> node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.node
> node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.js:13:23:
>
> ```
>   13 │ const Native = require("./fsevents.node");
> ```

I am using macBook air Monterey version 12.5 (M1, 2020), and this below is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-range": "^1.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "sass": "^1.62.0",
    "vite": "^4.3.0"
  }
```

I tried several ways below to fix this issue.

**1. modify Vite.config.js**

`optimizeDeps: { exclude: ["fsevents"] }`
In this case, there is no error on the terminal, but I can see only empty screen on the web browser and the console says

> caught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

**2. Use loaders**

So I tried to use "*node-loader*' and '*file-loader*' to make Vite load '.node' file successfully with changing 'vite.config.js' to apply the rules, but still it didn't work

**3. remove lines from vite.config.js**

`import { resolveBaseUrl } from 'vite';`

`import { defineConfig } from "vite";`

I found these two suggestions from other questions in Stack Overflow but the first line I didn't even have, and the other one gives me error:

> caught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (at ${mod.url}${sourceMapSuffix}`);:32482:5)

**4. Remove Node and reinstall it**

I removed node and all the relevant files and check that there's no more node, and reinstalled node, but again not working

**FYI: While trying these, I removed 'node_modules' and re-installed**

If anyone can help me to solve this issue, I would really appreciate it.
Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I'm stuck with the same issue.

Comment: ^ Wondering about this too? This failure started happening to me all of a sudden, and can't find what I might have done to cause it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and i found that vscode has accidentally imported the `loadConfigFromFile` method somewhere in my project and that had been the issue.

Try looking for other imports from `'vite'` where they shouldn't be.

Credit: [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/8140#issuecomment-1426849922)

Comment: Thank you ! It took me until I saw your message to see that VS Code had automatically imported something it should not have.